# ¿Por qué no retorna nada al ejecutar este script?

Tags: python

Deseo que la siguiente funcion devuelva una cadena al reves. Por ejemplo la cadena "hola" debería devolver la cadena "aloh".

```
def inversa(cadena):
    longitud = len(cadena)
    reversa = ""
    i = -1
    while i != 0:
        reversa = reversa + cadena[i]
        i = longitud - 1
    return reversa

print(inversa("hola"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código has creado un bucle infinito, analizemos la siguiente línea:

```
i = longitud - 1
```

`i` es igual a la `longitud-1`, longitud es el tamaño del string ingresado por lo que es fijo, haciendo que `i` tambien lo sea, en este caso particular `i = 4 -1 = 3`, y ese valor de `i` controla la ejecución del bucle, al ser siempre 3 nunca saldra del bucle ya que siempre 3 es diferente de 0.

Manteniendo tu idea de fondo la implementacion correcta es la siguiente:

```
def inversa(cadena):
    longitud = len(cadena)
    reversa = ""
    i = longitud-1
    while i >= 0:
        reversa = reversa + cadena[i]
        i -= 1
    return reversa

print(inversa("hola"))
```

Aunque la forma más *pythonica* es la siguiente:

```
def inversa(cadena):
    return cadena[::-1]

print(inversa("hola"))
```